# Using CDSAPI in google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I installed a python library called `cdsapi`in google colab.

To use it I need to locate its config file (which in a general Linux system is `$HOME/.cdsapirc`) and add my account key to it.

More details can be found here (https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api-how-to).

I am having a problem with this step

> Copy the code displayed beside, in the file $HOME/.cdsapirc (in your
> Unix/Linux environment): url: {api-url} key: {uid}:{api-key}

I tried using `!cd /home/` in colab notebook but it doesn't contain this file.

I have also tried `!cat /home/.cdsapirc`, it gave error:

> cat: /home/.cdsapirc: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this successfully. My code in Colab is as follows:
First, create '.cdsapirc' and write your key in root dir:

```
url = 'url: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2'
key = 'key: your uid and key'

with open('/root/.cdsapirc', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([url, key]))

with open('/root/.cdsapirc') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Then, install cdsapi:

```
!pip install cdsapi
```

Run example:

```
import cdsapi
c = cdsapi.Client()
c.retrieve("reanalysis-era5-pressure-levels",
    {
        "variable": "temperature",
        "pressure_level": "1000",
        "product_type": "reanalysis",
        "year": "2008",
        "month": "01",
        "day": "01",
        "time": "12:00",
        "format": "grib"
    }, "/target/dir/download.grib")
```

The target dir could be your google drive folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your UID, API key and CDS API endpoint directly as arguments into the constructor:

```py
uid = <YOUR UID HERE>
apikey = <YOUR APIKEY>

c = cdsapi.Client(key=f"{uid}:{apikey}", url="https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2")
```